# Bash Alias to Open Github Pull Request in Browser Window

Tags: bash, git, github

I'm trying to create a bash script to open a Github pull request in a browser window.

Here's the command I need to run:

---

open https://github.com/ParentOwner/**RepoName**/compare/**develop**...**JoshuaSoileau**:**CurrentBranch**

---

Where the things in bold need to be dynamic.

I need to figure out how to pull the following things in BASH:

```
RepoName       -   name of the repo
develop        -   ARGUMENT to my bash script
JoshuaSoileau  -   github username of the current user
CurrentBranch  -   name of the currently checked out git branch.
```

I know how to do the following:

```
RepoName       -   ??
develop        -   $1 argument in my bash script
JoshuaSoileau  -   ??
CurrentBranch  -   $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

---

**How do I pull the `1. RepoName` and `2. Current github username` in a BASH script?**

This is what I have so far:

```
git-open-merge() {
    open https://github.com/ParentOwner/??/compare/$1...??:$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
}
```

And it's called like this:

```
git-open-merge develop
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the user name: `git config --get user.name`

To get the repo: `git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's:.*/::;s:\.git::'`

`git config -l` to see what you have configured.